# Which system is this?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, filesystems, virtualization

I'm working on a project that build its image `.qcow2` based in a temporary file system generated in `/tmp/` folder. It looks like this:

```
$ls -la /tmp/
-rw-------  1 root root  7G Jan 30 09:55  image.eS1MjH2B
-rw-------  1 root root  26K Jan 30 09:55 tmp.GMB71AnHTa
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8K Jan 30 09:55 tmp.CL19PB8Lk1
-rw-------  1 root root  26K Jan 30 09:54 tmp.bRd8o91psP
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8K Jan 30 09:53 tmp.51EWL6SpfC
-rw-------  1 root root  26K Jan 30 09:52 tmp.lU3vK2IU8O
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8K Jan 30 09:51 tmp.qkpjM7KQS4
-rw-------  1 root root  26K Jan 30 09:51 tmp.8qEeIyOrGq
-rw-------  1 root root 3,8K Jan 30 09:50 tmp.AVLzwflgp0
```

I don't know which system, neither how this is made, but I really need to understand it because I can't do a proper `sudo -u` command inside of this filesystem while is building my image.

Any tip, comment, would be very helpful!
Thank you!

Comment: can we please get file sizes, too?

Comment: @vautee I updated my question.

Comment: Are you asking what file system type is used in the image file or something else?

Comment: @jlliagre Yes, and any other information related to it. I really don't know what is this and how to solve my problem.

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I can't do a proper `sudo -u` command inside of this filesystem while is building my image.

Comment: Please add the commands you run and the error message you get.

Answer (score 0):

Just a shot in the dark: Is it possible your filling a partition while building the image so that `sudo` doesn't find enough space for it's temporary files? You can test this with:

```
$ df -h
```

Comment: I think that is not the case here @Mathias, because even when the image is build I have at least 80G free space in my partition.

Comment: You'd want the `df -T` option to see the type of filesystems